# Tornado read X509 certificate from request header

Tags: java, python, tornado, x509certificate

How can I read the X509 certificate from an HTTP(S) request that comes into a Tornado server?  Similar code in java:

```
public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res) throws ServletException,
  IOException {
res.setContentType("text/plain");
PrintWriter out = res.getWriter();

X509Certificate[] certs = (X509Certificate[]) req
    .getAttribute("javax.servlet.request.X509Certificate");
```

Answer (score 2):

In a `RequestHandler`, use `self.request.get_ssl_certificate()`. To use this method you must also set the `cert_reqs` option in `ssl_options` when constructing the `HTTPServer`:

```
server = HTTPServer(app,
    ssl_options=dict(
        certfile="foo.crt",
        keyfile="foo.key",
        cert_reqs=ssl.CERT_REQUIRED,
        ca_certs="cacert.crt"))
```

http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/httputil.html#tornado.httputil.HTTPServerRequest.get_ssl_certificate